# Breaking an array into quadrants multiple times

Tags: java, arrays, bitmap

My goal is that I have an image which spits out a bitmap. Now I want display the average color of the image as one giant pixel. This is a fairly simple task, just use bufferImage and get the bitmap which I take each red, green, and blue value, add it all up and then divide by the picture's resolution.

The thing is after doing this, I want to break the image into four quadrants and take the average color for each quadrant and display it. And again break each of the four quadrants and do the same. The issue I am facing is that I am using a recursive statement that does the following:

```
private static void getBlockAverage(int startHeight, int endHeight, int startWidth, int endWidth, BufferedImage img, BufferedImage blockImg, Color oldAvg) {
        if(endHeight <= startHeight || endWidth <= startWidth) {
           counter++;
           return;
        }
        // get quadrant pixel average and display, I deleted this portion of the code just to keep things compact

        getBlockAverage(startHeight, (startHeight + endHeight)/2, startWidth, (startWidth + endWidth)/2, img, blockImg, color);
        getBlockAverage((startHeight + endHeight)/2, endHeight, startWidth, (startWidth + endWidth)/2, img, blockImg, color);
        getBlockAverage(startHeight, (startHeight + endHeight)/2, (startWidth+endWidth)/2, endWidth, img, blockImg, color);
        getBlockAverage((startHeight+endHeight)/2, endHeight, (startWidth+endWidth)/2, endWidth, img, blockImg, color);
    }
```

It is quite easy to see that this is not what I want as the recursive statement will keep executing `getBlockAverage(startHeight, (startHeight + endHeight)/2, startWidth, (startWidth + endWidth)/2, img, blockImg, color);` first until it is done and then move onto the next one. This is not what I want. I want the image to be broken down into 4 quadrants and then each of those quadrants gets broken down until all quadrants are broken down and continue.

So for example:

Starting off with 1 quadrants, break into 4. Now for quadrant 1, break that into 4, now quadrant 2, break that into 4, now quadrant 3, break that into 4, now quadrant 4, break that into 4.

Now that I am thinking about it, I feel like I should use some sort of for loop with a cap on the number of iterations but I am not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to agree with you. I think I would place this method into loop as well but also make the method return the average color for each quadrant into an single dimensional Array with the thought of each Array index is a quadrant number and and the actual element for that index contains the color for that particular quadrant. This way you can work with all the pertinent information that is acquired later on. I would at least get it going and then optimize it once it's working the way I want. Well, that's how I do it anyways :P

Of course I'm assuming throughout all this that the Quadrant dissection flow is something similar to what I show in the image below:

[image]

Here is what I would do:

Change the **getBlockAverage()** method so that it returns a Color...

```
private static Color getBlockAverage(int startHeight, int endHeight, int startWidth, 
            int endWidth, BufferedImage img, BufferedImage blockImg, Color oldAvg) {    

    // get quadrant pixel average color and return it
    // with whatever code you've been using....

    return theQuadrantAverageColor;
}
```

then I would create another method which contains our loop, image quadrants dissectional dimensions, and calls to the **getBlockAverage()** method while the loop is well...looping and for every loop cycle place the returned color from the **getBlockAverage()** method into a per-established Color Array:

```
private static void getQuadrantsColorAverages(Color[] quadrantColors, BufferedImage img) {
    // Decalre and Initialize required variables.
    BufferedImage wrkImg = img;
    BufferedImage blockImg = null; //?????
    int imgWidth = wrkImg.getWidth();
    int imgHeight = wrkImg.getHeight();
    int startHeight = 0;
    int endHeight = 0;
    int startWidth = 0;
    int endWidth = 0;
    Color oldAvg = null;
    int quadCount = 1;

    // Start our loop and and continue it until our counter 
    // variable named quadCount goes over 20....
    while (quadCount <= 20) {
        // Handle dissectional dimensions (in pixels)
        // for quadrants 1 to 20 as layed out within
        // the supplied image to this forum post.
        switch (quadCount) {
            // Quadrant 1
            case 1:
                startHeight = 0; endHeight = (imgHeight / 2);
                startWidth = 0; endWidth = (imgWidth / 2);
            // Quadrant 2
            case 2: 
                startWidth = (endWidth + 1); endWidth = imgWidth; 
                break;
            // Quadrant 3
            case 3: 
                startHeight = (endHeight + 1); endHeight = imgHeight;
                startWidth = 0; endWidth = (imgWidth / 2);
                break;
            // Quadrant 4
            case 4:
                startWidth = (endWidth + 1); endWidth = imgWidth; 
                break;
            // Quadrant 5
            case 5:
                startHeight = 0; endHeight = (imgHeight / 4);
                startWidth = 0; endWidth = (imgWidth / 4);
                break;
            // Quadrant 6
            case 6:
                startWidth = (endWidth + 1); endWidth = (imgWidth / 2);
                break;
            // Quadrant 7
            case 7:
                startHeight = (endHeight + 1); endHeight = (imgHeight / 2);
                startWidth = 0; endWidth = (imgWidth / 4);
                break;
            // Quadrant 8
            case 8:
                startWidth = (endWidth + 1); endWidth = (imgWidth / 2);
                break;
            // Quadrant 9
            case 9:
                startHeight = 0; endHeight = (imgHeight / 4);
                startWidth = (endWidth + 1); endWidth = ((imgWidth / 4) * 3);
                break;
            // Quadrant 10
            case 10:
                startWidth = (endWidth + 1); endWidth = imgWidth;
                break;
            // Quadrant 11
            case 11:
                startHeight = (imgHeight / 4); endHeight = (imgHeight / 2);
                startWidth = (imgWidth / 2); endWidth = ((imgWidth / 4) * 3);
                break;
            // Quadrant 12
            case 12:
                startWidth = (endWidth + 1); endWidth = imgWidth;
                break;
            // Quadrant 13
            case 13:
                startHeight = (imgHeight / 2); endHeight = ((imgHeight / 4) * 3);
                startWidth = 0; endWidth = (imgWidth / 4);
                break;
            // Quadrant 14
            case 14:
                startWidth = (endWidth + 1); endWidth = (imgWidth / 2);
                break;
            // Quadrant 15
            case 15:
                startHeight = (endHeight + 1); endHeight = imgHeight;
                startWidth = 0; endWidth = (imgWidth / 4);
                break;
            // Quadrant 16
            case 16:
                startWidth = (endWidth + 1); endWidth = (imgWidth / 2);
                break;
            // Quadrant 17
            case 17:
                startHeight = (imgHeight / 2); endHeight = ((imgHeight / 4) * 3);
                startWidth = (imgWidth / 2); endWidth = ((imgWidth / 4) * 3);
                break;
            // Quadrant 18
            case 18:
                startWidth = (endWidth + 1); endWidth = imgWidth;
                break;
            // Quadrant 19
            case 19:
                startHeight = (endHeight + 1); endHeight = imgHeight;
                startWidth = (imgWidth / 2); endWidth = ((imgWidth / 4) * 3);
                break;
            // Quadrant 20
            case 20:
                startWidth = (endWidth + 1); endWidth = imgWidth;
                break;
        }

        // Maintain the oldAvg Color variable
        oldAvg = getBlockAverage(startHeight, endHeight, startWidth, 
                                 endWidth, img, blockImg, oldAvg);
        // We subtract 1 from quadCount below to accomodate
        // our Array indexing which must start at 0.
        quadrantColors[quadCount - 1] = oldAvg;
        // increment our quadrant counter by 1.
        quadCount++;
    }
}
```

Then from somewhere in your application I would initiate all this like so:

```
// We declare our array to handle 20 elements since
// the image will be dissected into 20 quadrants.
Color[] quadrantColors = new Color[20];

BufferedImage img = null;

// Fill our Color Array...
getQuadrantsColorAverages(quadrantColors, img);

// Let's see what we managed to get....
for (int i = 0; i < quadrantColors.length; i++) {
    Color clr =  quadrantColors[i];
    int red = clr.getRed();
    int green = clr.getGreen();
    int blue = clr.getBlue();

    System.out.println("The average color for Quadrant #" + 
       (i + 1) + " is: RGB[" + red + "," + green + "," + blue + "]");
}
```

Well...that's it QQCompi. I hope it sort of helps you out a little.

Comment: Beautifully written, thanks a lot! This really helped me out